How to prevent additional whitespace when text is wrapped with grid or flexbox
I want to display a simple icon after some text. When the text is too long the text is wrapped but the icon is pushed to the right because the grid/flex item seems to want to use all available space.
I have the following HTML:
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div>Some very very very very very very very very very long piece of text</div>
    <div class="icon">I</div>
  </div>
</div>

The CSS using flexbox is defined as:
.wrapper {
  width: 100px;
}

.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.container .icon {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

I also tried using grid:
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 1fr) 1rem;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

In both situations I get the following result:
| Some very very very very very very     | I |
| very very very long piece of text      |   |

How can I get rid of the extra whitespace in the text column?
